# coding errors causing endless loop

Tags: java, syntax

I'm attempting to write a program that takes a population's birthrate and deathrate and loops the annual population until it either reaches 0 or doubles.

My problem it that it continuously loops an endless amount of illegible numbers and I can't fix it.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Hwk6 {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        int currentYear, currentPopulation;
        double birthRate, deathRate;
        Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("\nPopulation Estimator\n");
        System.out.println("Enter Year");
        currentYear = stdin.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter Current Population");
        currentPopulation = stdin.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter Birthrate of Population");
        birthRate = stdin.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Enter Deathrate of Population");
        deathRate = stdin.nextDouble();

        int counter = currentPopulation;
        System.out.println("Population: ");
        while (currentPopulation != -1)
            while (counter < currentPopulation * 2) {
                System.out.print(counter + " ");
                counter = counter + (int)(counter * birthRate - counter * deathRate);
            }
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Since this is a homework assignment, I'm hoping your professor has stressed the importance of commenting your code.  It's a good habit to get into because it allows the code reader a glimpse into what you thought you were doing and allows them to compare your thought process with the correct answer.  It may have allowed you to figure this problem out yourself, too, because you'd have noticed that the 
  
   -- while(currentPopulation != -1) --

loop was an infinite loop.  ;)

Answer (score 4):

Update the value of `currentPopulation` somewhere in your `while` loops, otherwise `while (currentPopulation != -1)` will **always** evaluate to true (unless `-1` was the original value), and you'll end up in an infinite loop.

Or maybe you meant

```
if (currentPopulation != -1)
```

instead of

```
while (currentPopulation != -1)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
while (currentPopulation != -1)
```

Your while condition will always be true, and hence it will iterate infinitely. Because you are not changing the value of `currentPopulation` inside your while loop anywhere.

You need to change the value of `currentPopulation` somewhere in your outer while loop, after your inner while loop ends.

```
while (currentPopulation != -1) {
     while (counter < currentPopulation * 2) {
           System.out.print(counter + " ");
           counter = counter + (int)(counter * birthRate - counter * deathRate);
     }

    // Change your `currentPopulation` here
}
```

Comment: how would i go about changing the currentPopulation if I dont know what the value is? seeing as the data is entered at startup. also, the value im supposed to enter is causing crash. im  to enter 6,500,400,321 with a birthrate of 0.12 and a deathrate of 0.11. it gives me this errorEnter Year
2011
Enter Current Population
6500400321
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException: For input string: "6500400321"
        at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2166)
        at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2119)
        at Hwk6.main(Hwk6.java:18)
[dkellogg@hills cs111a]$

Comment: Make your `currentPopulation` as type `long`. The value you entered is outside the range of `int`. Which is: - `[-2147483648 to 2147483647]`.